# looking for a way to download a list of packages with yum

Tags: linux, centos, rhel, yum, rpm

We are trying to setup a local repo that contains all the base packages. So to get started we need to download around 3500+ packages and save it in a folder that will be used as a Repo storage.

We have tried following:

```
1. for i in `cat pkg_list`; do yum install $i --downloadonly --downloaddir=/pkgs/; done
```

The above for loop fails when trying to parse the next value of $i because there is already a live yum process running.

```
2. yum install <all packages> --downloadonly --downloaddir=/pkgs/
```

In the above command, we are not sure how to pass all 3500+ package names.

Any ideas or suggestions would be really helpful! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ yum install --downloadonly --downloaddir=/pkgs/ `cat pkg_list`
```

You can specify multiple package names on the `yum` command line. The only caveat here is that your command line may become too long for the shell.

Thanks